# Switching Content Database caused data migration

Tags: 2010, content-database

I experienced something very strange with my development machine today, and want to ask all the SharePoint experts out there.

In my development environment I had a content database, this one is quite small with only testdata of 2 customers.

I needed to retrieve data from an old production database, so I went to CA, and removed my test-db, and added the old-prod-db (the old-prod-db is on a external HD).

When switching back by removing the old-prod-db and added the test-db in CA, everything went fine, except that the data from the old-prod-db started to pop up in my test-db.

I had only 2 customers in my test-db, and after an hour I had like 200, and two more hours, I had 1000+.

I should also mention that I forgot to delete the old DB from SQL, but since it was on an external drive, I simply physically removed it. And my development environment consist of 2 virtual machines, 1 SharePoint server and 1 Domain Controller with my database.

Hope you guys are still following me;

1. Where does the data come from? As I said, I have removed the old-prod-db disk from my machine.
2. Why is it copying data from old-prod-db to my test-db ?